# Looping through Multi Array with Wildcard powershell

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

Just seeing if anyone can get me over this hurdle.. tried many things and nearly have it but the wildcard is not matching. i have 2 arrays that will become many. some values have * next to them as i am using the like operator - that all works if looping through a single array btw

individually The first part of the loop will write this out as it should :

value1 value2 value3 Value4

The second part also writes out as it should like this

value1 value2 value3 value4

together they write out like this because of the loop.

value1 *value2* *value3* *value1* *value2* *value3* value4 value4

The problem is even though the $_ is registering the value when used in the context below $*.DisplayName -like $* it never returns a match i have also tried $*.DisplayName -like "$*" 
How can i get the wildcard to work in a multi array? It works in a single array but even tho i see the value returns in multi array it does not carry over to the actual command only the write-host?

not sure what i am missing.

```
$DisplayApps = @("value1", "*Value2*", "*value3*")
$Apps = @("Value4")

$MasterApps = @($DisplayApps,$Apps)

ForEach ($item in $masterapps)
{ 
  Write-host $item
    ForEach ($item in $item) 
    { Write-Host $item
      $AppVer = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path1 | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like $item }
         If($AppVer){ Write-Host "YES $item" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by not using $_ in your foreach loop. $_ is a reserved variable name. Use a non-reserved name.

Comment: Changed all $_ to $var and still no luck

Comment: @LDStewart what EBGreen was saying was that you need to change `$_` to `$item` because you have given the variable a name.  If you were doing a `Foreach-Object` you would use `$_`

Comment: All instances of $_ above are now $item except the $_.DisplayName and still it will not find the like match

Comment: "ForEach ($item in $item)" This makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your script locally and found a few issues.

As LDStewart pointed out in the comments above, you were misusing the $_ operator a bit.

Secondly, I can't find a property named "DisplayName" from the object Get-ItemProperty creates, however, there is a property named "Name" that contains the name of the item in the current iteration.

I updated your script with these changes and it seemed to me to produce the correct output:

```
$DisplayApps = @("value1", "*Value2*", "*value3*")
$Apps = @("Value4")

$MasterApps = @($DisplayApps,$Apps)

ForEach ($item in $masterapps)
{ 
  Write-host $item
    ForEach ($i in $item) 
    { Write-Host $i
      $AppVer = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path1 | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $i }
         If($AppVer){ Write-Host "YES $i" }
    }
}
```

If you want to investigate what kind of properties an object contains, you can use the "Get-Member" cmdlet to see all the properties, events and methods it contains. E.g. try running

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToOneFile | Get-ItemProperty | Get-Member
```

and it will tell you all the properties available.

Comment: just realized what the problem was - on my test machine the value4 needed to be asterisk value4 asterisk for the like operator to work... to match the registry - will mark your response correct tho. $path1 is a registry path btw